# Rsync is not copying my files over, why?

Tags: rsync

I use `rsync` to backup my files from my (x)Ubuntu desktop to one external USB drive (not a flash drive, a hard disk of the old spinning type.)

It works OK most of the time, the command I use is

```
rsync -Otvru ~/SavedStuff/ /mnt/datb3/data/SavedStuff > ~/SavedStuff.log
```

But today it failed on these files:

```
ls -ll --time-style=long-iso SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3 /mnt/datb3/data/SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acal acal 25380989 2005-08-16 11:22 /mnt/datb3/data/SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acal acal 25382220 2005-08-16 11:22 SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
```

Here is another way to show times:

```
stat SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3 /mnt/datb3/data/SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
  File: SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
  Size: 25382220    Blocks: 49576      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 50987363    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    acal)   Gid: ( 1000/    acal)
Access: 2020-01-27 16:04:40.908580904 +0100
Modify: 2005-08-16 11:22:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2020-01-22 13:24:55.977678797 +0100
 Birth: -
  File: /mnt/datb3/data/SavedStuff/Music_2/AYK1-3798/AYK1-3798_S2.mp3
  Size: 25380989    Blocks: 49576      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 13378890    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    acal)   Gid: ( 1000/    acal)
Access: 2019-08-21 08:25:53.671404757 +0200
Modify: 2005-08-16 11:22:50.000000000 +0200
Change: 2019-08-21 08:25:53.671404757 +0200
 Birth: -
```

I changed the metadata on the second file (on the desktop) and then I changed the date/time back to the original using "touch" (I prefer to keep the original date/time, even when/if I change these files)

Why this file is not transferred? My understanding was that the fast-check algorithm would use either date/time (here the same) or the file size (here different).

How can I investigate the reason why `rsync` ignores this file? And its companions, there are many, if it were just one I would just use `cp`.

Thanks!

OK, so it appears that I was way too inaccurate in setting the times. Since getting times exactly right appears difficult, I should remove the -u option from my command line, that explicitly tells rsync to ignore files newer on the receiver - no matter what the file size.

Thanks for telling me about the `stat` command!

Comment: Here is the log file, I think the file was just ignored.

Comment: sending incremental file list

sent 672,170 bytes  received 2,037 bytes  1,348,414.00 bytes/sec
total size is 45,560,115,122  speedup is 67,575.86
sending incremental file list

sent 672,170 bytes  received 2,037 bytes  1,348,414.00 bytes/sec
total size is 45,560,115,122  speedup is 67,575.86

Comment: can you use `stat` to get file times ? how do you change time ? did you set time manually  or use a reference file ? (my guess is USB file are a few millisec ahead of hard drive's one)

Comment: I change file times with two scripts, one saves the original desktop times and another one resets them after my modifications. Sorry about the bad formatting, I can't see how do it right.

Comment: USB file is 50 sec ahead of disk file, thus more recent.

Comment: Please put your updates into your question. You can format them, and it's easier for us to read them and help you.